# Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I get this error while building Object Recognition Kitchen and have no idea what to do:

```
[ 24%] Building CXX object object_recognition_core/src/io/CMakeFiles/voter_ectomodule.dir/module_voter.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/tomas/ork/devel/lib/object_recognition_renderer/trainer_planar
[ 24%] Built target trainer_planar
[ 24%] Building CXX object object_recognition_core/src/db/CMakeFiles/db_ectomodule.dir/ModelWriter.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object object_recognition_core/src/db/CMakeFiles/db_ectomodule.dir/ObservationReader.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object object_recognition_core/src/db/CMakeFiles/db_ectomodule.dir/ObservationWriter.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/tomas/ork/devel/lib/libobject_recognition_core_common.so
[ 25%] Built target object_recognition_core_common
Linking CXX shared library /home/tomas/ork/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_recognition_core/boost/common.so
[ 25%] Built target common_interface
Linking CXX shared library /home/tomas/ork/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_recognition_core/ecto_cells/voter.so
[ 25%] Built target voter_ectomodule
Linking CXX shared library /home/tomas/ork/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_recognition_core/ecto_cells/db.so
[ 25%] Built target db_ectomodule
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

This is for catkin_make -j1

```
Base path: /home/tomas/ork
Source space: /home/tomas/ork/src
Build space: /home/tomas/ork/build
Devel space: /home/tomas/ork/devel
Install space: /home/tomas/ork/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/tomas/ork/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1" in "/home/tomas/ork/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RecognizedObject
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionGoal
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TableArray
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionActionResult
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionActionFeedback
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RecognizedObjectArray
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectInformation
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionFeedback
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetObjectInformation
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Table
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionResult
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectType
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionAction
[  0%] Built target _object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectRecognitionActionGoal
[  5%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  5%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  9%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  9%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  9%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  9%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  9%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  9%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 13%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 13%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages
[ 13%] Built target object_recognition_renderer_2d
[ 14%] Building CXX object ork_renderer/src/CMakeFiles/object_recognition_renderer_3d.dir/model.cpp.o
In file included from /home/tomas/ork/src/ork_renderer/src/model.cpp:30:0:
/home/tomas/ork/src/ork_renderer/src/model.h:33:21: fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [ork_renderer/src/CMakeFiles/object_recognition_renderer_3d.dir/model.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ork_renderer/src/CMakeFiles/object_recognition_renderer_3d.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219475/invoking-%22make--j8--l8%22-failed/) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-10-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-20**:
The actual error is most likely somewhere earlier. Please try `catkin_make -j1` and copy/paste the actual error message in your question (use the *edit* button/link for that).

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-10-20**:
@gvdhoorn I just edited my question

**Comment by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on 2015-10-20**:
it seems you don't have access to SDL/SDL.h. Can you post the complete path of this header?

**Comment by [johnny zhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30724/johnny-zhou/) on 2017-06-10**:
`catkin_make -j1`  helped me. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Hi I get this error while building Object Recognition Kitchen [..]

Have you ran `rosdep check --from-paths /home/tomas/ork/src --ignore-src` to make sure you have all required dependencies installed on your system (such as SDL)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-10-23**:
I got this. What does it means? I'm a total newbie to these problematics.

```
System dependencies have not been satisified:
apt libosmesa6-dev
apt meshlab
apt libsdl1.2-dev
```

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-23**:
It means you forgot to install your dependencies before building. Try a similar rosdep command, but substitute `install` for `check`.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-10-23**:
Substitute `check` for `install`?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-23**:
No, run `rosdep install --from-paths /home/tomas/ork/src --ignore-src`

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-10-24**:
It helped thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-24**:
Thanks @joq. Reason I asked to run `check` first is because I don't like to give ppl commands that could potentially break their system. Running `rosdep install ..` would've been in a follow-up edit.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-24**:
@gvdhoorn: I quite agree, but was concerned that @sykatch still didn't seem to understand the problem.

**Comment by [addext](https://answers.ros.org/users/45331/addext/) on 2019-09-03**:
hi, I ran `rosdep check --from-paths /my/path/to/workspace --ignore-src` and got `All system dependencies have been satisfied`. Any ideas?

**Comment by [Paul Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/46783/paul-sebastian/) on 2019-10-15**:
@addext. Even I got the same thing. Did you solve it?

**Comment by [addext](https://answers.ros.org/users/45331/addext/) on 2019-10-28**:
@Paul Sebastian I did not solve it "the clean way". After struggling with it for days, I ended up reinstalling ubuntu and ROS.